# Qual a finalidade de ConcurrencyStamp e SecurityStamp no ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, dapper

O sumário de ambas as propriedades na entidade [`IdentityUser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-2.1) estão em inglês:

**ConcurrencyStamp:** *A random value that must change whenever a user is persisted to the store.*

Traduzindo seria algo *mais ou menos* assim:

> Um valor aleatório que deve mudar sempre que um usuário for persistente no repositório.

**SecurityStamp:** *A random value that must change whenever a users credentials change (password changed, login removed).*

Traduzindo seria algo *mais ou menos* assim:

> Um valor aleatório que deve mudar sempre que houver alterações nas credenciais do usuário (Senha alterada, login removido).

Estou utilizando o Dapper ao invés do EF com o Identity e o **ConcurrencyStamp** nunca atualiza, então pensei que seria melhor entender a finalidade deles.

O **ConcurrencyStamp** eu fiquei bem confuso, e já o sumário do **SecurityStamp** conseguiu descrever bem. Porém eu fiquei super confuso quando me deparei com [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39001084).

E o que eu acreditava ser função do **SecurityStamp** aparentemente é função do **ConcurrencyStamp**.

- Quais são as finalidade dessas propriedades/colunas da tabela?
- Preciso fazer algo para que, por exemplo, o **ConcurrencyStamp** realize sua função corretamente com o Dapper? Me pareceu necessário após ter visto [esta resposta usando o EF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37362173).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ConcurrencyStamp** representa o **atual** estado dos dados no repositório e ele é necessário para evitar problemas de concorrência. Exemplo:

- Um admin abre o registro de um usuário para editar seu endereço de email
- Outro admin também abre o registro do mesmo usuário para a mesma coisa
- O primeiro admin atualiza o email e salva
- Quando o segundo admin for salvar, o **ConcurrecyStamp** estará **diferente** (porque os dados que ele havia carregado já foram mudados) e assim lançando uma exceção.

**SecurityStamp** faz a mesma coisa mas com as informações relacionadas com as credenciais do usuário. Se ele desloga ou troca a senha o SecurityStamp muda, invalidando cookies antigos e outros possíveis problemas de segurança.

Sobre o dapper, aparentemente não precisa fazer nada. Na resposta que você mencionou, ele apenas mostra a implementação do `IdentityDbContext` para "provar" a explicação acima.